# Refreshing a view in Gtk3-Ruby

Tags: ruby, gtk3

I'm having a problem changing a view in my feed reader. When a button in the feed list is clicked, the feed window is supposed to update. Instead, the feed window stays empty. How do you remove and replace a widget in gtk3-ruby?

The problem method:

```
  def feed=(feed)
      @feed.destroy()
      @title, @count = feed.channel.title, feed.items.size
      @label.set_markup "<b>#{@title} (#{@count} articles)</b>"
      @feed = FeedItems.new(feed.items, @parent)
      self.pack_end(@feed)
      @feed.show()
  end
```

The full source is on pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/KPKAfCmx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have used `show_all` and the widget updates.

```
def feed=(feed)
    self.remove(@feed)
    @title, @count = feed.channel.title, feed.items.size
    @label.set_markup "<b>#{@title} (#{@count} articles)</b>"
    @feed = FeedItems.new(feed.items, @parent)
    self.pack_end(@feed)
    self.show_all
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! `show_all` was the trick! I've used `gtk_widget_show_all` in my C code.